# setting up proxy in chromedriver with authentication in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to set up different types of proxies(HTTP/SOCKS4/SOCKS5) with authentication in my selenium.
I have tried these two methods with no luck. What's the problem?

First try:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
var proxy = new Proxy
        {
            HttpProxy = $"http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}",
            SslProxy = $"https://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}",
            IsAutoDetect = false,
            Kind = ProxyKind.Manual
        };
```

Second try:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
proxy.HttpProxy = $"{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}";
proxy.SslProxy = $"{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}";
string proxyAuth = $"{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}";
options.AddArgument($"--proxy-auth={proxyAuth}");
```

The main part of the code which runs chromedriver:

```
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.Proxy = proxy;
options.BinaryLocation = path_to_chrome + @"\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe";
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path_to_chrome);
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

I tried both methods along with initializing options.Proxy = proxy; and sending that to ChromeDriver. Chrome starts normally but I can see that it's not using my proxies when I check the IP inside the browser.

Comment: This is only possible using a chrome-extension.

Comment: You're right! using an extension is the only way to achieve this. Thanks a lot